# Split string and string arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, split

```
string s= abc**xy**efg**xy**ijk123**xy**lmxno**xy**opq**xy**rstz;
```

I want the output as string array, where it get splits at "xy". I used

```
  string[] lines = Regex.Split(s, "xy");
```

here it removes `xy`. I want array along with `xy`. So, after I split my string to string array, array should be as below.

```
lines[0]= abc;
lines[1]= xyefg;
lines[2]= xyijk123;
lines[3]= xylmxno;
lines[4]= xyopq ;
lines[5]= xyrstz;
```

how can i do this?

Comment: What language do you need this in?

Comment: Please add the language you're using to the tags. Is it C#?

Comment: Language i am using is C#

Comment: It would be nice if your code above were valid C#. It takes our time otherwise to fix the code before we can provide a working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?=xy)
```

You need to split on `0 width assertion`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/50

```
string strRegex = @"(?=xy)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"abcxyefgxyijk123xylmxnoxyopqxyrstz";

return myRegex.Split(strTargetString);
```

Output:

`abc
xyefg
xyijk123
xylmxno
xyopq
xyrstz`

Answer (score 2):

If you're not married to Regex, you could make your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Ssplit(this string InputString, string Delimiter)
{
    int idx = InputString.IndexOf(Delimiter);
    while (idx != -1)
    {
        yield return InputString.Substring(0, idx);
        InputString = InputString.Substring(idx);

        idx = InputString.IndexOf(Delimiter, Delimiter.Length);
    }

    yield return InputString;
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = "abc**xy**efg**xy**ijk123**xy**lmxno**xy**opq**xy**rstz";
var x = s.Ssplit("xy");
```

Comment: I quite like the way you're going with this, but I think it would be an awesome answer if you used `yield return` rather than `List<string> output`.

Comment: @Enigmativity -- thanks for the insight and suggestion.  I am not "classically trained" in C# and can be guilty of brute-forcing solutions.  I've done some reading on `yield return` and modified my suggestion per your feedback -- and I've added this to my toolbox.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems fairly simple to do this:

```
string s = "abc**xy**efg**xy**ijk123**xy**lmxno**xy**opq**xy**rstz";

string[] lines = Regex.Split(s, "xy");

lines = lines.Take(1).Concat(lines.Skip(1).Select(l => "xy" + l)).ToArray();
```

I get the following result:

[image: lines]

I don't know if you wanted to keep the `**` - your question doesn't make it clear. Changing the RegEx to `@"\*\*xy\*\*"` will remove the `**`.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply looping throgh the array starting with index 1 and adding the "xy" string to each entry?

Alternatively implement your own version of split that cuts the string how you want it.

Yeat another solution would be matching "xy*" in a non-greedy way and your array would be the list of all matches. Depending on language this probably won't be called split BTW.

Comment: Please don't offer suggestions without the actual solution. As it stands your answer is more like a big comment.

Comment: Sometimes a hint in the right direction is worth more than the solution itself. By the way, all three other answers given so far show implementations of my three suggestions ;-)

Comment: If this were a Question & Hint site I would agree, but this is a Question & Answer site. You should stick to full answers. The overarching purpose of Stack Overflow is not to just provide an answer to the person who posted the question but to provide the answer over and over again to people who browse this question in the future. It's only with good questions and good answers is this purpose met.